# If statement does not trigger

Tags: java

I have a problem where my if condition doesn't trigger properly and I have no idea why.
Here is the function calling `ModelField`:

```
public void squareMaker(){
    for (int i = 0; i<=_model.getSizeofgame()-1; i++){
        _squares.add(new JButton());
        _model.Modelfield(i, 'u');
        _squares.elementAt(i).setBorder(_border);
        _squares.elementAt(i).setActionCommand("" +i);
        _squares.elementAt(i).addActionListener(_controller);
        this.add(_squares.get(i));
        System.out.println("Square in gamepanel " + i);
    }
}
```

And the actual function in model:

```
public void Modelfield(int pos, char symb){
    int position=pos+1;
    System.out.println("Adding square in model "+position +" boardsize "+boardsize);

    if((position%boardsize)==0){
        System.out.println("Right edge "+position);
        if(position<=Boardwidth){
            modelVector.elementAt(position).redge=true;
            System.out.println("Top and Right edge ");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Not top edge");
        }
    }
    else {
    }
    modelVector.addElement(new Fieldpiece(position,symb));
}
```

So what is supposed to happen is that when I call Modelfield from squareMaker it never gets past the
`if((position%boardsize)==0)`

Does anyone have any clue why?

Comment: you might want to start using spaces in your code

Comment: Maybe the statement is never true?

Comment: What is the actual output of those `println`s?

Comment: A little more spacious code wouldn't hurt. Whats the output of your syso? Methods shouldn't start with uppercase: ModelField -> modelField()

Comment: whats the value of `boardsize`?

Comment: Are you sure that `_model.getSizeofgame()` returns the same value as `boardsize`?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if the statement:

```
if((position%boardsize)==0){
```

doesn't fire, it's because `position % boardsize` isn't equal to zero.

Finding out *why* is basic debugging 101: if code isn't acting the way you think it should be, output all information that *affects* the code.

For example, inserting the following lines before your `if` statement:

```
System.out.println ("=====");
System.out.println ("position  = " + position);
System.out.println ("boardsize = " + boardsize);
System.out.println ("modulo    = " + position % boardsize);
System.out.println ("=====");
```

then examining the output, which should hopefully tell you *exactly* what the problem is (you could also run/step your code through a debugger if you don't want to examine the output generated by this method).

If you already *have* code that you think outputs enough information to debug, you should examine *that* (and show us the output if you want our help). In this case, it'll consist of the output lines beginning with:

```
Adding square in model
```

Comment: OP is already printing position and boardsize, that should be enough.

Comment: @Keppil: yes, I just noticed that. Amended the answer to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but my guess is that when `position%boardsize` executes, it does not `== 0`. I would check to make sure the values of `position` and `boardsize` reflect your expectations and troubleshoot from there.